# How can I run current editor line in active terminal in VS Code and then move editor cursor to next line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to send the selection to active Terminal. Also I realize that shift + enter can send the current line to a new Python terminal. However, I am not able to figure out how to send the current line (i.e. the line I have cursor on) to the active terminal. I would like to cursor to move down after sending the line to the active terminal. I tried everything in related posts.

Comment: use `runCommands` and construct a sequence of commands to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+b",     // whatever you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "cursorEnd",            // these two commands select the current line
      "cursorHomeSelect",
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "echo '${selectedText}'\u000D",  // your python command here
        }
      },
      "cursorDown"
    ]
  },
  // "when": ""   
},
```

`\u000D` is a return - so the command will run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as something like this (put this in keybindings.json, which you can open by running `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b", // TODO put whatever key combo you want here
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        "cursorDown",
    ]},
},
```

`workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText` will just run the current line (with leading whitespace trimmed) if nothing is selected, so I don't think you need to write the text selection stuff that Mark has in their answer post. If you want to keep leading whitespaces, you'd need something like Mark's answer but with `cursorHomeSelect` twice in a row.

Since Python was involved in the motivation of this specific question, be aware that this will mean you don't get [the smart send feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_improvements-to-run-line-in-the-terminal).

Comment: "if nothing is selected" - safer to assume there could be something or nothing selected.